# Is there a less repetitive way to search through a list for class objects that meet parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

Right now my code looks like this

```
class TEST:
    _list= []
    def __init__(self, atribute1, atribute2, name):
        self.atribute1 = atribute1
        self.atribute2 = atribute2
        self.name = name
        self.__class__._list.append(self)
    

    def __get__(Key,Value):
        if Key == 'atribute1':
            for thisObj in TEST._list:
                if thisObj.atribute1 == Value:
                    print(thisObj.name)
                else: print('\n stop')
        elif Key == 'atribute2':
            for thisObj in TEST._list:
                if thisObj.atribute1 == Value:
                    print(thisObj.name)
                else: print('\n stop')
        else: print('unsuported values')

alpha = TEST(0,1, 'Alpha')
beta = TEST(0,1, 'Beta')
theta = TEST(1,0, 'Theta')
```

The `__get__` method right now is very repetitive and jumbled, however it  only way I've gotten it to work. What my desired out come is to be able to enter
`DECK.__get__(atribute1,0)` and have it print every class object that matches those parameters in this case `Alpha` and `Beta`.
I know you can do something like return `[x for x in list if [Key] == Value]` when you have a dictionary list. So I tried to translate that into this application like so `x for x in TEST._list if x.[Key] == Value` (and a billion other variations) but it keeps thinking Key is an undefined variable. Which, technically it is, Key and Value could be any combination of things. In my real application (not this example) I need to have a possible 7-9 Keys so repeating the code like my example above is more than a little daunting, Especially when I start thinking about all the other things this class method needs to be able to do (mostly just differentiate whether its being called on by a person or by a different method).

**Long story long, Any advice and or clarifying questions?**

Comment: @JonSG so basically i can use __dict__ to go like `x for x in TEST._list if x.__dict__[Key] == Value`

Comment: Did you not see `getattr()` as the number one answer?